# LSTMによる時系列電力量予測データを作りたい

Tags: python

大学の卒業研究で、とある二七年間分（10000件）の電力量時系列データを用いて一日の稼働と非稼働かを判断するプログラムを組むことになりました。
自分はプログラミング初心者なのですがこのようなことは可能なのでしょうか？
また、もしも可能であるのならば詳しいやり方を教えてはいただけないでしょうか？
お手数をおかけして申し訳ございません

Comment: 回答には、時系列データのサンプル、稼働/非稼働の基準が必須と思われます。

Comment: > `詳しいやり方を教えてはいただけないでしょうか？` それを教えてしまった場合、あなたの卒業研究ではなくなってしまうのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。当方建築学生でして建築設備にAIをというテーマで卒業研究を進めています。人間の目視により電力の稼働、非稼働を基準を決め、その基準からExcel macroとLSTMによる精度の比較をはかろうという研究です。しかし、プログラミングというものを初めて体験したのですがうまく実装することが叶わずこのサイトにたどり着きました。プログラミングの本などで勉強はしているのですが、如何せん我流のせいかうまくことが運んでいないのが今の状況です。すいません自分の卒業研究にならないのではないかというお言葉、至極その通りだと思います。ですが今のままでは遅々として研究が進まないので何か勉強によいサイトや役立つことがあればそれだけでも教えてはもらえないしょうか。ご迷惑をおかけして申し訳ございません。

Comment: 「サイトや役立つことを教えて下さい」という質問としては非常に広い範囲かつ一意絞られづらく、残念ながら今の質問はスタックオーバーフローでは回答が付きづらいでしょう。「上手く実装することが叶わず」とおっしゃっているということは、何かしら試したのだと思います。実際に「やろうとしたこと」「できなかったこと」をざっくりではなく、ミクロに質問してみてはいかがでしょうか？たとえば「エラーが出てできなかった」や「返ってきたデータが違っていたとか」や「ファイルの読み込みができない」等です。

Comment: 色々と親身に答えてくださりありがとうございます！！自分が実践したことも踏まえてミクロに新たに質問を建ててみようと思います。ご助言ありがとうございました！